# Retrieve ID of JSON when POST in Firebase, Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, post, firebase-realtime-database

I POST a JSON into my Firebase Database, using okHttp. Then I retrieve a response and I do:

```
response.body().string();
```

But when I print this, instead of a JSON I get:

```
/**/ gotData({"name":"my_object_ID"});
```

I want to extract the JSON inside of that String.

Comment: what is the query url you use ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise I was using an url ending in "?callback=gotData", I removed this and now works perfectly.

Comment: yep, that was what I thought.